# is it reasonable having a packet with gso_size > 0 and < 64 byte?

Tags: linux

Is it "reasonable" to have a gso_size > 0 and < 64 byte?

I have seen that in some particular GRO use cases, the gso_size is set to a value less than 64 byte.

The standard what does it say? I am not able to find nothing around it.

Thx in advance!!!